# Is it a possible of p-adic number to euclidean geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, p-adic-number-theory

I was reading about theorem called Monsky's theorem stating that "A square can never be divided into an odd number of traingles of equal area " . 
I read that the proof uses something called 2-adic valuation . I don't know anything about p-adic systems but know that "It is a slightly different number system where the proximity of two numbers is obtained by the number of times their gap is divisible by a certain prime number p " and unknowingly I consider p-adic to be advanced mathematical stuff . 
So , I was excited to find a possible instance where advanced mathematics being used in complicated problems of school geometry . 
Am I right in concluding that these 2-adic valuation is not same as real number systems as we know it  and this is indeed one instance where higher maths is being applied to euclidean geometry ?

P.S: On a different note , how difficult a question would it be in a maths contest if it asks to prove " A square cannot be divided into odd number of triangles of equal area " ?

Answer (score 2):

The geometry of $p$-adic numbers is very different from the geometry of real numbers. For instance, any triangle in $\mathbb{Q}_p$( set of $p$-adic numbers) is isosceles, which is clearly not the case for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So , this 2-adic valuation is something different as compared to the normal coordinate system , right ?